# Converting UnmanagedMemoryStream to the System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, memorystream, canon-sdk

I use the EDSK to convert the memory stream to image it gives the following error at

> Error:Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> Line:readStream.Read(outMessage, 0, (int)streamLength);

```
                unsafe
                {
                    uint streamLength;
                    if (Error == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
                    {

                        Error = EDSDK.EdsGetLength(streamRef, out streamLength);
                    if (Error == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
                    {
                        UnmanagedMemoryStream readStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)(void*)streamRef.ToPointer(), streamLength, streamLength, FileAccess.Read);
                        // Create a byte array to hold data from unmanaged memory.

                        byte[] outMessage = new byte[streamLength];

                        // Read from unmanaged memory to the byte array.
                        readStream.Read(outMessage, 0, (int)streamLength);

                        readStream.Close();

                        Image img = byteArrayToImage(outMessage);
                        img.Save("C:\\temp\\test.jpeg");

                    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow you don't seem to want to check `Error` after you call `EdsGetLength` Do you have insight, as to whether it returns a valid `streamLength`?

Comment: yes it return streamLength = 4754647

Comment: Any particular reason why you cast streamRef to void* before casting it to byte* ?

Comment: no but it gives the same error with and with out void*

Comment: Looking at [some sample code](https://github.com/ofTheo/CanonCameraWrapper/blob/master/CanonCameraWrapper.cpp), using streamRef.ToPointer() is wrong.  You must call EdsGetPointer() to get a pointer to the image data.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the mention error the issue is resolved by getting the pointer by EdsGetPointer()